# Using find in Bash to find single folder in folder

Tags: bash, macos, unix, find

I was wondering if there was a way, in a given file path, to find all of the folders that contain a single folder. Whether that folder contains anything at all or hundreds of files is irrelevant.

Sudo Directory Tree:

```
- /A/
    - /Aa
    - /Ab
    - /Ac
- /B/
    - /Ba/
    - /Bb/
    - /Bc/
    - /Bd/
    - /Be/
    - /Bf/
    - /Bg/
- /C/
    - /Ca/
```

I basically want to find C because its contents are just a single directory.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#
# __PATH__ => directory whose tree we want to search
#
for dir in $(find __PATH__ -type d -print)
do
    dcount=$(ls -l $dir | grep -c '^d')
    if [ $dcount -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo $dir
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find /path/to/search -type d | awk -F/ '{$NF=""}1' OFS=/ |
     sort | uniq -c | awk '$1==1{print $2}'
```